# Dynamic merge in R

Tags: r, merge

I have an example filter table as below and a big source data table. I need to do the merge using these two tables. If no column in the filter table contains ALL, use three columns to do the the merge (using  `Tran=1001`, `Acct=1` & `Co=a` to do the inner join with the data table).If one of them, ie Tran has ALL, use the remaining two columns to do the merge (using `Acct=3` & `Co=c` to do the join). If two of them, ie `Tran` and `Acct`, have `All`, use the remaining one column to do the merge (using `Co=b` to do the join).

The real question is the number of columns is uncertain.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
Tran    Acct    Co
1001    1        a
1002    ALL     ALL
ALL     ALL      b
ALL      4      ALL
1003     2      ALL
ALL      3       c
1004     ALL    d
```

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for the editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to write a series of conditional statements using `if`, `elseif` and `else`. I'll use the `%in%` operator to check for this. The `%in%` operator returns a series of boolean values. The easiest way is to show through example:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> y <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> x %in% y
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Notice that it returns `FALSE` for the first value as the value of `1` in `x` is not in `y`. You can do the same for the "ALL" value in your data set. I assume you are going row by row as you seemed to imply in your question. Let me know if you need to check the whole column first (you can use the `any` function for that case). Here is an example of your first condition:

```
# Assume that df is your data.frame of data.

for (i in 1:length(df$Tran)) {

if (!("All" %in% df$Tran[i]) & !("ALL" %in% df$Acct[i]) & !("All" %in% df$Co[i])) {

# Do your merge here

}

if ( [Put your next condition here] ) {

# Do the appropriate merge for that condition

}

...
```

Note that I used the "!" operator to get the inverse of whatever `%in%` returns because you want it to be the case where ALL is NOT in the row. I realize now that you could have just done `All != df$Tran[1]` since you are going row by row, but `%in%` might be more useful if you end up going for the whole column.

Hope this helps!

---

Editing in a new method now that it's more clear what the need is. So we have to find the number of "ALL" values in each row and then merge a certain way depending on the number of them. There are a lot of methods, but here's one I like:

```
> test <- data.frame(a = "ALL", b = 2, c = "ALL", d = 3, e = "ALL")
> test
    a b   c d   e
1 ALL 2 ALL 3 ALL
> table(test[1, ] == "ALL")["TRUE"]
TRUE 
   3
```

Basically, I'm looking at the first row, and getting the number that return TRUE when asked if it contains the string "ALL". From here you can set conditionals on this number. To automate over the entire data frame, throw it in a for loop and set "1" equal to "i" or whatever you sequence variable is.

---

To get which rows have "ALL" in it (which in converse would tell which  rows do not have "ALL" in it as well), you can use `grep` on each row. Here's a short example:

```
> # Initializing a sample data frame.
> df <- data.frame(a = "1", b = "ALL", c = "ALL", d = "5", e = "ALL")
> print(df)
  a   b   c d   e
1 1 ALL ALL 5 ALL
> 
> # Finding the column numbers that have "ALL" in it using grep.
> places <- grep("ALL", df[1, ])
> print(places)
[1] 2 3 5
> 
> # Each number corresponds to the order of the columns in the data frame and can be returned as such.
> nameCols <- names(df)[places]
> print(nameCols)
[1] "b" "c" "e"
> 
> # Likewise, you can find what columns did not have "ALL" in it by doing the opposite.
> nameColsNOT <- names(df)[-places]
> print(nameColsNOT)
[1] "a" "d"
```

Iterate this method through a loop for each row in your data frame and use the conditional method I outlined above. Please note that this requires your columns to all be of "character" class, which I assume is the case already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One important thing is that we do not know how many columns will be in the filter table. It can be 3, 5 or 7 columns. I use 3 as an example.

Comment: Okay, so this will help. Do you check to see if "ALL" is in each row or anywhere in each column?

Comment: My thinking is to check if ALL in each row and count how many ALLs in each row. Then split the filter table into small tables. Tran=1001, Acct=1 & Co=a will be in a table. Acct=3 & Co=c will be in a table. Co=b will be in a table. In total 1+3+3=7=2^3-1 tables. At the end join 7 tables with the data source. But when it comes to n columns, it will need Cn1+Cn2+Cn3+...+Cnn=2^n-1 tables.

Comment: Does it matter which column has "ALL" in it or do you simply need the number that have "ALL" in it per row. If the latter case, see my edit in my answer above.

Comment: The column matters. If Tran has all, I need to use the other to do the join; if Acct has all, I need to use Tran and Co to do the join.

Comment: Ah okay, I added a method to do that using `grep` into my answer above, see that for details.

Comment: Thanks for this method. It gives me some thinking. I believe I can solve this problem now.